# Play/stream from a Windows PC to multiple Bluetooth speakers at once

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

I'd like to use my Windows PC to stream/play music to 4/5 Bluetooth speakers at a small party outside, but Windows let me select only one of them per time.

Is it possible to stream to multiple speakers at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering this myself and it looks like this bit of software is what we both need: http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows

I'm waiting to hear back from them about how many devices it can stream to and also whether I understood their feature list correctly but it looks like it will do the job. There's a mac version too.

NB: It's $25 to purchase a licence

Comment: Umm... how does that help?

Comment: Only with mac airplay speakers actually. Seems there just isn't a way to do it with any old bluetooth speakers